# Why is second <input> value not set in local storage?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get user input. It is working, but only for the first input. The second input is not set in local storage. I got multiple inputs, and when i type in second input, it is not captured. Why?

**Javascript**

```
(function () {
  $(document).on("input", function () {
    data = $("input").val();
    localStorage.setItem("test", data);
  });
})();
```

**HTML**

```
 <form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Because `$('input')` selects all inputs, and in that case, `.val()` only gets the value of the first input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening for any `input` event on the *document*, when I would assume you actually want to update only when there's a change in the *input* fields - So two changes first; making sure you're targeting the input fields, and using the `change` event rather than input

```
$(document).on("input", function () {
// to
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
```

Also, you're going to be overwriting the entry called `test`, because both inputs are sending to the same entry - You could pass in the `name` attribute instead, for example

```
data = $("input").val();
localStorage.setItem("test", data);
// to
localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
```

Here's a demo of it all together, on [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/_Light/pen/xxbPeEb)

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the value from the target of the event, but from the first input in the document, as you can see here:

```js
$(document).on('input', (e) => {
  // This will always return the same input (the first one):
  console.log($('input').attr('name'));
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name:">
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name:">
```

So this:

```
$(document).on("input", () => {
  // Always returns the value of the first input:
  const data = $("input").val();
  localStorage.setItem("test", data);
});
```

Should be this:

```
$(document).on("input", (e) => {
  // Returns the value of the input that has changed:
  const data = $(e.target).val();
  localStorage.setItem("test", data);
});
```

Also, you might want to save all the values of all the fields that change, not only the last one (as you are always overwriting the same `"test"` prop, so you could use the name of the field (`e.target`) as key:

```js
const localStorageContent = $('#localStorageContent');

// As we can't use localStorage in snippets:
const fakeLocalStorage = {
  setItem(key, value) {
    this[key] = value;
  },
  getItem(key) {
    return this[key];
  },
};

$(document).on('input', (e) => {
  const $target = $(e.target);
  fakeLocalStorage.setItem($target.attr('name'), $target.val());
  
  localStorageContent.text(JSON.stringify(fakeLocalStorage, null, '  '));
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name:">
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name:">

<pre id="localStorageContent"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `val` as a [getter](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val1), it only gets the value of the **first** element in the jQuery set you call it on, not all of them.

If you want all of them, you'll need to loop through the set. For instance, if you want an object with name/value pairs for the fields, you might use `get` to get an array of the jQuery object's elements (perhaps just the ones that are `text` fields), then `map` to map them to an array containing arrays compatible with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), and then use `Object.fromEntries` to create the object. Since that's an object, not a string, to store it in local storage you need to convert it to a string.  You might use JSON:

```
var entries = $("input:text").get().map(({name, value}) => [name, value]);
var data = Object.fromEntries(entries);
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Live Example:

```js
var entries = $("input:text").get().map(({name, value}) => [name, value]);
var data = Object.fromEntries(entries);
console.log("Would store:", JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Later if you want the object, you'd use `JSON.parse` to parse the string from local storage back into an object:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
console.log(data.firstname); // Shows the value that was stored for `firstname`
```

---

I should also note that you're grabbing the values on page load. Those values will be empty, since there are no default values for them defined in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's returning Error: `Iterator value abc is not an entry object` Why is that?

Comment: @grevvx4 - Huh, I'm surprised by that. I've updated the code so it doesn't use jQuery's `map`.